# Connecting MySQL with C++/ C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mysql-connector

I know C++ and (MySQL with PHP). But now I need to connect MySQL with C++. I need help for MySQL server , MySQL Connector settings and configuration of Code::Blocks as well as connection code. Please help me.
I know only Code::blocks or Visual Studio only. Any thing about MySQL server and Connector connector I don't know for C++ connection. Please help me.

Comment: Try using MySql Connector C++: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: Thanks Thomas Matthews.I have downloaded it .But still can not do any thing that how to connect and others sites in net did not also speak details about configuration .

Comment: Strange.  I have found many examples on the MySql sites and other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2010 setup the following :

- MySQL SERVER 5.5.38      ( mysql-5.5.38-win32.msi )
- MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3 ( mysql-connector-net-6.8.3.msi )

In Visual Studio =>> File =>> New =>> Project =>> Visual C++ =>> CLR =>> CLR Empty Project

[image]

After opening the project, View =>> Solution Explorer =>> On Project Name Right Click =>> Properties =>> C/C++ Or Configuration Properties =>> General =>> Additional Include Directories =>> Click to edit and write:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\include (or that directory  where you had installed MySQL and Mention its include folder).

E.g. ( C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include )

[image]

Now in same properties dialog navigate to Linker =>> General =>> "Add additional Library Directories" =>> (write the path of folder which contains .dll or .lib files e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC)

E.g. ( C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.0 )

[image]

In same properties dialog navigate to Linker =>> Input =>> Additional Dependencies =>> (write the name of .lib file you want to use e.g. libmysql.lib or any other library you want to use which is placed in above "Additional Library Directories"). E.g. ( libmysql.lib )

[image]

And at last if it not work then please go to C:\Program Files\MySQL\include (or that directory where you had installed MySQL and Mention its include folder).

Then in Windows Search option search write "libmysql.lib". Then copy this lib file in your project bin debug,release folder. Also some times it may say in error message for requirements of some other lib or DLL file.

Do same process search in MySQL directory and copy-paste them.  If this not work then copy the above mentioned DLL, lib file in each folder of your project then in it must work. I did in this way.

MySQL code for connection in Database:

```
#include "my_global.h"
#include "mysql.h" 
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD ""
#define DATABASE "database" 
int main()
{
    char ch;
    clock_t begin, end;
    //MYSQL *connect=mysql_init(NULL); 
    //connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0); 
    //if( ! connect) { printf("MySQL Initialization or Connection Failed!\n"); return 0; }
    //mysql_query(connect,"insert into test values(2)");

    //mysql_query(connect,"INSERT INTO student VALUES('111','aaaa','bbbb')");
    begin = clock();
    //printf("Application SN\tMerit\tAdmission Roll\n-------------- ------- ----------------\n");
    MYSQL_RES *res_set; MYSQL_ROW row; 
    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM database");
    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);  //unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);   
   // while ( row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set) )
       //printf("  res  %s\t",row[0]); /* Print the row data */ 
    end = clock();
    printf("Execution Time: %f seconds\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    mysql_close(connect);  
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    //getch();
    //cin>>ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MySql Connector C++ and Visual Studio (2008 and 2010).

You will need to search the web for "MySql Connector C++ examples".  Too much information to duplicate here.

Also search StackOverflow for "C++ connect mysql".

There are other connectors as well that you may want to try out.

See [MySql Connector developer's guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**working code here :**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<winsock.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include <mysql.h> 


using namespace System;



int main()
{
    MYSQL conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res_set; 
    MYSQL_ROW row; 

   mysql_init(&conn);

   if (!mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","root","","TestDB",0,NULL,0))
   {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to database: Error: %s\n",
          mysql_error(&conn));
   }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Successfully connected to Database.\n");
        int status= mysql_query(&conn,"SELECT * FROM Login");
        res_set = mysql_store_result(&conn); 
        int count=mysql_num_rows(res_set);
        printf("No of rows = %d\n",count);

        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL) 
       { 
           for (int i=0; i<mysql_num_fields(res_set); i++) 
           { 
              printf("%s \t",row[i] != NULL ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
           }
           printf("\n");
        }
     }

    mysql_close(&conn);
    getchar();
    return 0;


}
```